# Intersection of Decreasing closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis, cauchy-sequences

If $\{E_n\}_{n \in N}$ is a sequence of closed nonempty and bounded sets in a complete metric space $(X,d)$, if $E_n \supset E_{n+1}$ and if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{diam} E_n = 0,$$ then $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$$ consists of exactly one point.

**Attempt**:

Since $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{diam} E_n = 0,$$ this implies $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (d(p_n,q_n)) = 0$$ for $p_n,q_n \in E_n$. Therefore, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} d(p_n,q_n) = 0$$ so that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n = x = \lim_{n \to \infty} q_n.$$ by definition of a metric. Thus, since $E_n \supset E_{n +1}$, we see that $x \in E_n$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n = \{x\}$$ as desired.

I believe this proof is incomplete, since I didn't use the fact that the $E_n$'s are closed, or that $X$ is complete. Where am I mistaken? Please, no complete answers, as this is homework.

Comment: In fact, you claim that $x\in E_n$, for which  step that you use  the closed fact implicitly.

Comment: I think you have to justify the step from $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(p_n,q_n)=0$ to $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n=x=\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n$, you have to explain why $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n$ exist, and I believe this is where you use the completeness of $X$.

Comment: @FrankLu Well I said that this limit must exist by definition of a metric, since $d(x,y) = 0$ iff $x =y$, so that this limit must exist. Or is that not quite enough?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(p_n,q_n)=0$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n$ provided both limit exist.

Comment: @FrankLu Okay, so can I say that $d(p_n,p_m) \leq \operatorname{diam} E_n$ since $E_n \supset E_{m}$ for $m>n$. Right? Thus since $\operatorname{diam} E_n$ converges to $0$, $d(p_n,p_m)$ is Cauchy which converges to $x$ since $X$ is complete. Is this right?

Comment: Exactly, that is the point.

Comment: @FrankLu Thank you for your help.